# using sourceLabel in istio is not working

Tags: istio

I am trying to filter access to external ressources. I have created a service entry

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: bbc-ext
spec:
  hosts:
  - "www.bbc.co.uk"
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
```

I am using sourceLabel to filter the source app allowed to access external ressources.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bbc-ext
spec:
  hosts:
  - "www.bbc.co.uk"
  http:
  - match:
    - sourceLabels:
        envir: "production"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "www.bbc.co.uk"
      weight: 100
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: "www.bbc.co.uk"
    fault:
      abort:
        percent: 100
        httpStatus: 400
```

My pod is labeled `envir=development` but is still allowed access to the ressource.

```
kubectl get pods --show-labels
NAME                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       LABELS
sleep-d7bfccf65-ws6t6   2/2       Running   0          16m       app=sleep,envir=development,pod-template-hash=836977921
```

But, when I log in the container and run a curl request it is still valid. What am I doing wrong here?

```
kubectl exec -it sleep-d7bfccf65-ws6t6  -c sleep bash
root@sleep-d7bfccf65-ws6t6:/# curl -v -sL https://www.bbc.co.uk -w "%{http_code}\n"    -o /dev/null
 [...]
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Encoding, X-CDN, X-BBC-Edge-Scheme
<
{ [data not shown]
* Connection #0 to host www.bbc.co.uk left intact
200
```

still the same.

also noticed that sync is not working for routes.

```
istioctl proxy-status
PROXY                                                  CDS        LDS            EDS               RDS          PILOT
istio-egressgateway-6cb5b78857-cvqfz.istio-system      SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     NOT SENT     istio-pilot-56f6487cdb-qlhzr
istio-ingressgateway-5766b9cc69-64bgd.istio-system     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     NOT SENT     istio-pilot-56f6487cdb-qlhzr
sleep-86f6b99f94-n8l8r.production                      SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-56f6487cdb-qlhzr
sleep-d7bfccf65-qbs7v.development                      SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-56f6487cdb-qlhzr
```

Comment: I have not found any examples of using regex in  `VirtualService` could you try to use static route for example `www.bbc.co.uk` and check is it work or not?

Comment: still the same. also noticed that sync is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/4026